# Is there a way to embed websites using Content Security Policies within other webpages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, embed, content-security-policy

When I try to embed this on my website I get an error:

```
<a href="https://gamebanana.com/maps/198412"><img alt="Share banner" src="https://gamebanana.com/maps/embeddables/198412?type=small"/></a>
```

The error I get is:

> The loading of “https://gamebanana.com/maps/198412” in a frame is
> denied by “X-Frame-Options“ directive set to “DENY“.

**see screenshot**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nZdH.jpg

When I click "Learn more" it brings me here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

I need a way to bypass the CSP, which I'm sure is done by setting parent objects. However, I am uncertain of how to do this 100%. Could someone please assist me in successfully embedding this object without running into this error?

Thank you!

Comment: No can do! It is the site owner's prerogative to disallow others to display their site and content in a frame. You can't control the remote site's headers

Comment: I am able to do this with my Twitch stream by setting parent objects.

Comment: <html>
  <body>
    <div id="twitch-embed"></div>
    <script src="https://embed.twitch.tv/embed/v1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed", {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        channel: "sourceinvite",
        parent: ["sourceinvite-wixsite-com.filesusr.com", "sourceinvite.wixsite.com"]
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: That is a completely different case as they intend you to do an embed. Lots of sites don't want you to. Can't embed google in a frame for example

Comment: Kind of figured just wanted a definitive from someone elses brain. thx!